# Jeckyll (Static-Site Generator) not displaying assets on posts

Tags: image, web, github-pages

I'm building my first static-site generator blog. This technology seemed like the right one to document my progress in 3D Printing, I don't need any fancy and all of the features of Jeckyll is what I would need to continue in this process. I'm hosting the blog via Github Pages and it is an installation of Poole, which is fork of Jeckyll.

Jeckyll ask you to have an specific hierarchy of files and _assets/ is the folder where you should store any media that you wish to share of display in the posts. The way to call these assets is by writing this on the posts.

> … which is shown in the screenshot below:
>   ![My helpful screenshot]({{ site.url }}/assets/screenshot.jpg)

Now, I have done these in several ways but nothing is working properly. My local installation of the website shows everything working but the images come out with a question sign inside a square. What would be the right way, or the cautions I should be taking?

Here are my codes: https://github.com/Casa-Mucaro/Impresiones3D/tree/gh-pages
and here is the website: http://casa-mucaro.github.io/Impresiones3D/

Comment: I'm looking at your posts but not seeing an instance of using an image like you are describing.

Comment: Also, instead of doing `{{site.url}}/assets/screenshot.jpg` you could simply do `/assets/screenshot.jpg` and use a relative instead of absolute structure. Not sure if that would actually fix the problem you are having, but it's another option.

Comment: Your syntax is ok and working. Maybe you can put a test page in your repository to show us non working code.

Comment: My apologies, I have made some modifications to make my point much clearer. If you look at the first post, called El Comienzo: Parte 1. You could scroll down the page and see that instead of an image I get !Cabeza (highlighted) but I was hoping that instead of that, a picture would show up. Now, if you click the hyperlink you will be taken to a 404 Github Page: https://github.com/Casa-Mucaro/Impresiones3D/_assets/20140716/cabeza.webp. Also, is the use of webp instead of .jpg or .png works? I'm going to see if I could replicate some of the problems along the post, as the post should have images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some error in your code :

In configuration :

```
url:      http://casa-mucaro.github.io
baseurl:  /Impresiones3D

#underscored folder are ignored by jekyll at build time
include: _assets
```

[Image markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img)

```
![Alt text](/path/to/img.jpg "Optional title")
```

And with the base url (note: no space at all) :

```
![Libro]({{site.baseurl}}/_assets/20140716/reflibro.jpg)
```

Small detail : The actual code produces an error at build time, one yaml front matter needs to be quoted in _posts/2014-07-16-el-comienzo-(Parte-1).md.

```
---
...
title: 'El Comienzo: Parte 1'
```

Comment: So this worked perfectly, in my local installation. GithubPages link still doesn't show up the picture (instead shows up the question mark inside a transparent window). And I had to make some changes to your suggestions in editing the configuration file. The edits in the configuration files responded with a broken website. If instead I wrote in the url: http://casa-mucaro.github.io/Impresiones3D. The whole websites comes up but the pictures still are missing... even though they are working fine at my local machine... now that is confusing... what are your thoughts?

Comment: Actually, never mind. Instead I changed the image markdown syntax from the {{site.baseurl}} to {{site.url}} and made the url (in the configuration file) be http://casa-mucaro.github.io/Impresiones3D. Thank you!